# LINQ - Splitting up a string with maximum length, but not chopping words apart

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple LINQ Extension Method...

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string input, int length)
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < input.Length)
        {
            if (index + length < input.Length)
                yield return input.Substring(index, length);
            else
                yield return input.Substring(index);

            index += length;
        }
    }
```

This takes a string, and it chops it up into a collection of strings that do not exceed the given length.

This works well - however I'd like to go further. It chops words in half. I don't need it to understand anything complicated, I just want it to be able to chop a string off 'early' if cutting it at the `length` would be cutting in the middle of text (basically anything that isn't whitespace).

However I suck at LINQ, so I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how to go about this. I know what I am trying to do, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

So let's say I have the following text.

> This is a sample block of text that I would pass through the string splitter.

I call this method `SplitOnLength(6)`
I would get the following.

- This i
- s a sa
- mple b
- lock o
- f text
- that I
- would
- pass t
- hrough
- the s
- tring
- splitt
- er.

I would rather it be smart enough to stop and look more like ..

- This
- is a
- sample

> // bad example, since the single word exceeds maximum length, but the length would be larger numbers in real scenarios, closer to 200.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll solve this by for loop:

```
var ret1 = str.Split(' ');
var ret2 = new List<string>();
ret2.Add("");
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in ret1)
{
    if (item.Length + 1 + ret2[index].Length <= allowedLength)
    {
        ret2[index] += ' ' + item;
        if (ret2[index].Length >= allowedLength)
        {
            ret2.Add("");
            index++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ret2.Add(item);
        index++;
    }
}
return ret2;
```

first I thought about a Zip, but it's not good here.

and differed execution version with yield:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SaeedsApproach(this string str, int allowedLength)
{
    var ret1 = str.Split(' ');
    string current = "";
    foreach (var item in ret1)
    {
        if (item.Length + 1 + current.Length <= allowedLength)
        {
            current += ' ' + item;
            if (current.Length >= allowedLength)
            {
                yield return current;
                current = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return current;
            current = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not split the word if it exceeds the specified length (the result will exceed the maximum length), and also will not split at punctuation.

Comment: @jay, yes but I do this because of `// bad example` of OP because I think OP wants to have valuable result not just splitting.

Comment: This is a lot of imperative code, though. This has very good performance vs some other solutions, but Regex is more powerful, concise, and performant in this use case.

Comment: @Jay - This code 1) does understand whitespaces, only spaces, 2) keeps unwanted spaces in front of words, 3) outputs empty lines with multiple whitespaces. Plus if you have a big string it will allocate a big array, as it does not uses "yield". I 100% agree your Regex (1st solution) is a lot better - well, you're the Regex expert, I find it cryptic :-), but I measure it as being ~15% slower than my proposal.

Comment: @Simon Mourier, Ok you saying this code is not good as your code, I can simply change it to do `yield` but I'm sure my code speed is very faster than yours, your code is O(n^2) in the case of string length but this code traverse string list just 2-time and is 2*n (one for split one for doing action) but @jay, I'll test your code and if is better than this I'll edit this to more elegant way, but add to list to the end of your code. I think, it can't be 4 time faster never.

Comment: @Saeed- About your code, I'm not speaking about perf, and I don't say you code is not good, I'm speaking about functionality & scalability. If a string is composed of say 10000 words, you will allocate a list of 10000 strings before spitting the first. If I only need the 10 first for example, this does not scale well.

Comment: @Saeed: This solution is unscalable in two senses: larger input strings will require more and more allocation right off the bat due to the `string.Split` call (this is quite separate from your use of `List<string>` or `yield`; you use `string.Split` in both). Then higher and higher `length` parameters will require more superfluous string allocations due to the use of `+=` for string concatenation. You may see good performance in a very specific context—small input string, low `length` parameter—but this is far from an ideal general solution.

Answer (score 4):

## Update 2

I noticed in [Saeed's other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556151/linq-splitting-up-a-string-with-maximum-length-but-not-chopping-words-apart/4562247#4562247) that he skipped my suggestion since it threw an exception. This is an interesting topic. Whenever we as developers work on a solution to a problem, we need to consider the exceptional cases—the unexpected inputs, the invalid states, etc. I felt that since the requirement of the question was:

> I just want it to be able to chop a
>   string off 'early' if cutting it at
>   the length would be cutting in the
>   middle of text (basically anything
>   that isn't whitespace).

...that, in the event that *this is impossible* (i.e., in order to return a substring of the specified length it is *necessary* to cut a word in half because the word is too long), it would be appropriate to throw an exception. But obviously this is a subjective matter. However, realizing that there is more than one way to skin this cat, I have updated my solution (both on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3kz1ig7a) and below) to take a `WordPolicy` enum rather than a simple `bool`. This enum has three values: `None` (equivalent to `false` from before), `ThrowIfTooLong` (equivalent to `true` from before), and `CutIfTooLong` (if the word *must* be cut, just cut it).

I also added benchmarks of some of the other answers**, included below. Note that this time around I tested multiple runs with different `length` parameters (5, 10, 25, 200, 500, 1000). For the shortest `length` (5), the results seem somewhat even, with Saeed's suggestion on top. As `length` grows larger, the performance of Saeed's suggestion grows worse and worse. Simon's and Jay's suggestions appear to be significantly more scalable in the case of large inputs.

Also keep in mind that the OP has explicitly said that the value for `length` would be "closer to 200" in a realistic scenario; so using 200 as an input is not contrived. It is in fact a realistic case.

### New Benchmarks

```
Enter a split size: 5

Results from longer input:
Saeed (original): 2.8886 ms
Saeed: 3.2685 ms
Dan: 3.3163 ms
Simon: 7.4182 ms
Jay: 36.7348 ms

Results from shorter input:
Saeed (original): 0.031 ms
Saeed: 0.0357 ms
Dan: 0.0514 ms
Simon: 0.1047 ms
Jay: 0.2885 ms

Go again? y

Enter a split size: 10

Results from longer input:
Dan: 1.8798 ms
Saeed: 3.8205 ms
Saeed (original): 4.0899 ms
Simon: 4.9869 ms
Jay: 14.9627 ms

Results from shorter input:
Dan: 0.022 ms
Saeed (original): 0.0396 ms
Saeed: 0.0466 ms
Simon: 0.0483 ms
Jay: 0.2022 ms

Go again? y

Enter a split size: 25

Results from longer input:
Dan: 0.6713 ms
Simon: 2.7506 ms
Saeed: 4.5075 ms
Saeed (original): 4.7827 ms
Jay: 6.3477 ms

Results from shorter input:
Dan: 0.0131 ms
Simon: 0.0301 ms
Saeed (original): 0.0441 ms
Saeed: 0.0488 ms
Jay: 0.1176 ms

Go again? y

Enter a split size: 200

Results from longer input:
Dan: 0.1952 ms
Jay: 1.5764 ms
Simon: 1.8175 ms
Saeed (original): 6.8025 ms
Saeed: 7.5221 ms

Results from shorter input:
Dan: 0.0092 ms
Simon: 0.0206 ms
Saeed: 0.0581 ms
Saeed (original): 0.0586 ms
Jay: 0.0812 ms

Go again? y

Enter a split size: 500

Results from longer input:
Dan: 0.1463 ms
Jay: 1.2923 ms
Simon: 1.7326 ms
Saeed (original): 8.686 ms
Saeed: 9.1726 ms

Results from shorter input:
Dan: 0.0061 ms
Simon: 0.0192 ms
Saeed (original): 0.0664 ms
Saeed: 0.0748 ms
Jay: 0.0832 ms

Go again? y

Enter a split size: 1000

Results from longer input:
Dan: 0.1293 ms
Jay: 1.1683 ms
Simon: 1.7292 ms
Saeed: 11.7121 ms
Saeed (original): 11.8752 ms

Results from shorter input:
Dan: 0.0058 ms
Simon: 0.0187 ms
Saeed (original): 0.0765 ms
Jay: 0.0801 ms
Saeed: 0.084 ms

Go again? n
```

<sub>**Unfortunately, with the "large" input (the short story), I couldn't test Jay's original approach which was *incredibly* costly—an unbelievably deep call stack due to the recursion, plus an insane number of very large string allocations due to the `string.Substring` call *on a huge string*.</sub>

---

## Update

I hope this doesn't come across as defensive, but I think there is some very misleading information being presented amidst the comments and some other answers here. In particular [Saeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556151/linq-splitting-up-a-string-with-maximum-length-but-not-chopping-words-apart/4556325#4556325), the *accepted* answer, has some definite efficiency shortcomings. This wouldn't be such a big deal except that Saeed has claimed in some comments that *other* answers (including this one) are *less* efficient.

### Comparison of performance

First of all, numbers don't lie. [Here is a sample program I wrote](http://pastebin.com/3X6RwGh8) to test the method below as well as Saeed's method against example inputs, long and short.

And here are some sample results:

```
Results from longer input:
SplitOnLength: 0.8073 ms
SaeedsOriginalApproach: 4.724 ms
SaeedsApproach: 4.9095 ms

Results from shorter input:
SplitOnLength: 0.0156 ms
SaeedsOriginalApproach: 0.0522 ms
SaeedsApproach: 0.046 ms
```

**SplitOnLength** represents my method below, **SaeedsOriginalApproach** represents the *first* suggestion in Saeed's answer, and **SaeedsApproach** represents Saeed's updated answer using deferred execution. The test inputs were:

- The entire text of Franz Kafka's 'In the Penal Colony' (a short story—long input)
- An excerpt from the text of the OP's question (short input)
- A `length` parameter of 25 (to accommodate some longer words)

Notice that **SplitOnLength** executed in a *fraction* of the time of the methods suggested in Saeed's answer. I will concede, however, that the `length` parameter is likely to have an effect on this. With a smaller `length`, I wouldn't be surprised to see the performance of **SaeedsOriginalApproach** and **SaeedsApproach** improve significantly*.

### Explanation

Now, just a few remarks on what I think is going on here. Right off the bat, Saeed's answer starts with a call to `string.Split`. Now here's [something interesting Microsoft has to say about this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

> The Split methods allocate memory for
>   the returned array object and a String
>   object for each array element. If your
>   application requires optimal
>   performance or if managing memory
>   allocation is critical in your
>   application, consider using the
>   IndexOf or IndexOfAny method, and
>   optionally the Compare method, to
>   **locate a substring within a string**. *[emphasis mine]*

In other words, the `string.Split` method is not endorsed by Microsoft as an appropriate way to achieve optimal performance. The reason I highlight the last line is that Saeed seems to be specifically questioning the efficiency of answers that use `string.Substring`. *But this is the most efficient way to solve this problem*, period.

*Then* inside the method suggested by Saeed, we have code that looks like this:

```
ret2[index] += ' ' + item;
```

*This is the reason I believe that the performance of Saeed's approach degrades with higher and higher length parameters. As those of us who've been bitten by the performance of string concatenation before know, this is allocating a new string object on every append, which is wasteful. The problem only becomes worse as `length` gets longer. Notice the `SplitOnLength` method below **does not suffer from this problem**.

Another way of looking at this is simply by breaking down the different steps that need to take place. Below, let **N** be the length of the input string and **K** be the specified maximum length of a substring.

#### Saeed's answer

1. First, `string.Split(' ')`. This requires enumerating over the entire string once, and the allocation of a string object for every word in the string—which is likely to be more than we need (we're almost *certainly* going to concatenate some of them)—*as well as* an array to contain these objects. Let the number of strings in the array now be **X**.
2. Then there is a *second* enumeration over the X results of #1. During this enumeration, there are 0–X string concatenations using `+=`, allocating between 0–X *new* string objects.

#### `SplitOnLength` (below)

1. The string is likely *never* enumerated fully. There are at *most* N comparisons performed, but in a more realistic case the number is less than N. This is because on each iteration the algorithm optimistically goes straight to the next "best" index and only steps backwards if/as necessary to find the most recent whitespace.
2. The only new string objects allocated are *exactly* those that are needed, using `string.Substring`.

`string.Substring`, by the way, is very fast. It can be because there is no "extra" work to do; the exact length of the substring is known in advance, so there is no waste created during allocation (as would happen with, e.g., the `+=` operator).

Again, the reason I am adding this behemoth update to my answer is to point out the performance issues with Saeed's suggestion and to dispute his claims about the alleged efficiency problems in some of the other answers.

---

## Original Answer

My instinctive approach was to start with what you had and augment it slightly, with the addition of a little bit of code that would:

1. Check if `index + length` is followed by a whitespace; and, if not:
2. Step backwards into the string until finding a whitespace.

Here's the modified `SplitOnLength` method:

```
enum WordPolicy
{
    None,
    ThrowIfTooLong,
    CutIfTooLong
}

public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string input, int length, WordPolicy wordPolicy)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < input.Length)
    {
        int stepsBackward = 0;

        if (index + length < input.Length)
        {
            if (wordPolicy != WordPolicy.None)
            {
                yield return GetBiggestAllowableSubstring(input, index, length, wordPolicy, out stepsBackward);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return input.Substring(index, length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return input.Substring(index);
        }

        index += (length - stepsBackward);
    }
}

static string GetBiggestAllowableSubstring(string input, int index, int length, WordPolicy wordPolicy, out int stepsBackward)
{
    stepsBackward = 0;

    int lastIndex = index + length - 1;

    if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(input[lastIndex + 1]))
    {
        int adjustedLastIndex = input.LastIndexOf(' ', lastIndex, length);
        stepsBackward = lastIndex - adjustedLastIndex;
        lastIndex = adjustedLastIndex;
    }

    if (lastIndex == -1)
    {
        if (wordPolicy == WordPolicy.ThrowIfTooLong)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The input string contains at least one word greater in length than the specified length.");
        }
        else
        {
            stepsBackward = 0;
            lastIndex = index + length - 1;
        }
    }

    return input.Substring(index, lastIndex - index + 1);
}
```

This approach has the advantage of not doing *more* work than necessary; note the absence of any `string.Split` call and the fact that `string.Substring` is only called in the places where the result is actually being returned. In other words, no superfluous string objects are created using this method—only the ones you actually want.

Comment: string.Substring will be called n/k time if k is small (nearly all time) the number of calls will be O(n) and your algorithm will be O(n^2). also if you want fix your code for medium size of my example and add it to test result to compare it.

Comment: @Saeed: I believe you have some serious misconceptions about the performance of this and other suggested algorithms as compared to the one you yourself have suggested. I believe that yours has some serious efficiency shortcomings, and this is verified by my benchmarks. See my update and let me know if you have any thoughts or corrections to make to what I've said.

Comment: +1 Great update. Out of curiosity, what happens when you run my approach and Simon's in your benchmark?

Comment: @Jay: I will do that and let you know!

Comment: @Jay: Done—see my update. Clearly I have gotten quite carried away with this question; it's time to get back to work!

Comment: @Dan Tao, If I wanna do string manipulation with a string of size small story, I'll do it with StringBuilder, and if is bigger string I'll using sqlserver to do it, See `OP`s exact problem, `OP` doesn't have a big length parameter, length parameter is near to real word size, from the samples you can understand it, Also what you said about performance from MS was by memory allocation not by speed, I know influence on speed but it's not a main topic, and I just claim about speed, in the real scenario, Also about Jay, I just said that his first answer is not good because of stack usage and -->

Comment: substring calls, but if you wanna highlight my suggestion about substring usage (and I think in the case of question) and make small font my suggestion about stack usage I can't beleive this is a fair communication to continue it, but about += you are right, but is faster for valuable inputs, and If you think each program should be optimum in all cases you should do a big challenge find the grow speed of different algorithm by input size and use them by related input, also use stringbuilder, or sql in related cases.

Comment: @Saeed: The OP said that the length would be closer to 200 in a real-world scenario, so that is I think the ballpark number we should be focusing on. As for speed, your first comment to this answer remarked on the number of times `string.Substring` would be called; my point is that you have grossly overinflated the cost of this and neglected to consider that your own suggested algorithm *starts* with `string.Split`, which *right off the bat* results in a potentially high number of substring operations, *then* performs a potentially large number of concatenations...

Comment: @Saeed: (continued) But I think my example benchmarks are fair to your algorithm in that they do indicate it performs quite well with very small values for the `length` parameter. But **again, the OP has indicated that a more realistic value would be around 200**, which is why I believe your algorithm is simply not well suited to this problem.

Comment: I think `since the single word exceeds maximum length` means 200 is the length of maximum word not `allowed length`, may be I'm wrong, but never I said that my algorithm is better than others, until I see Jay said his answer is 4 time faster and Simon, continued Jay's way to saying my answer is bad, I'll say again if the `length` in OP's example is not maximum length, I'll choosing another way. this is a trade of between different way and inputs and each of them useful in specific scenario, so the best way is combination of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String.Split(' ')` to turn the single string into an array of individual words. Then, iterate through them, building the longest string that (with the spaces re-added) is less than the limit, append a newline and yield.

Comment: Nice approach.  Note however that the OP was not adding newlines.

Answer (score 1):

I suck with LINQ too :-), but here is a code that works without allocating anything (except output words of course), removes whitespaces, removes empty string, trims strings, and never breaks words (it's a design choice)  - I'd be interested to see a full LINQ equivalent:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string input, int length)
{
    if (input == null)
        yield break;

    string chunk;
    int current = 0;
    int lastSep = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsSeparator(input[i]))
        {
            lastSep = i;
            continue;
        }

        if ((i - current) >= length)
        {
            if (lastSep < 0) // big first word case
                continue;

            chunk = input.Substring(current, lastSep - current).Trim();
            if (chunk.Length > 0)
                yield return chunk;

            current = lastSep;
        }
    }
    chunk = input.Substring(current).Trim();
    if (chunk.Length > 0)
        yield return chunk;
}
```

Comment: In each iteration doing `input.Substring(current, lastSep - current)` is time consuming.

Comment: This stacks up very nicely. See the results I posted in Saeeds "test" answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had to put an answer forward as I felt that the other answers relied too much on indexing and complicated logic. I think my answer is quite a bit simpler.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string input, int length)
{
    var words = input.Split(new [] { " ", }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    var result = words.First();
    foreach (var word in words.Skip(1))
    {
        if (result.Length + word.Length > length)
        {
            yield return result;
            result = word;
        }
        else
        {
            result += " " + word;
        }
    }
    yield return result;
}
```

The result for the sample string provided in the OP is:

```
This is
a
sample
block
of text
that I
would
pass
through
the
string
splitter.
```

Answer (score 0):

#### update:

The one-liner:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string s, int length)
    {
        return Regex.Split(s, @"(.{0," + length + @"}) ")
            .Where(x => x != string.Empty);
    }
```

I've profiled this versus the accepted answer with ~9,300 character source (lorem ipsum x4) split at-or-before 200 characters.

10,000 passes:
 - loop takes ~4,200 ms
 - mine takes ~1,200 ms

#### original answer:

This method will shorten the result to avoid breaking words, except when the word exceeds the specified length, in which case it will break it.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string s, int length)
{
    var pattern = @"^.{0," + length + @"}\W";
    var result = Regex.Match(s, pattern).Groups[0].Value;

    if (result == string.Empty)
    {
        if (s == string.Empty) yield break;
        result = s.Substring(0, length);
    }

    yield return result;

    foreach (var subsequent_result in SplitOnLength(s.Substring(result.Length), length))
    {
        yield return subsequent_result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jay, this can be done without using call stack also `s.Substring(result.Length)` is not good if the string length is big.

Comment: @Jay - are you sure the 2nd proposal works? It seems to break words. If I use the original text "This is a sample block of text that I would pass through the string splitter", it breaks "through" in "t" + "hrough"?

Comment: Jay, the time you wrote is for regex compilation, you should do `ToList` at the end of your Where clause.

Comment: @Simon It breaks words only if a single word exceeds the length parameter. As you rightly point out, it breaks after the first character of the word instead of the nth, but as Saeed also rightly pointed out, the aim in this case is something useful for large strings broken at around 200 characters.

Comment: @Saeed That is not correct or necessary in this case. `Where()` is called after evaluation of the `Regex`. That said, adding `.ToList()` brings the time up to between 1900 and 2000 ms (for 10,000 iterations), still faster, at least for a large split.

Comment: @Jay, but my tests says another thing. I added yield, Where never called untill it's usage, in runtime you will just create an expression tree not iterating items, also if you have another test case edit my comparision answer and add your test case to test it.

Comment: @Saeed I added my test, which I modified to show averages, but I had to go with ticks instead of milliseconds because the average in some cases was below 1 ms.

Comment: @Jay - ok, I got it. It's because the result was not the same as the 1st algorithm, so I was confused :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string source,int maxLength)
{
   //check parameters' validity and then
   int currentIndex = 0;
   while (currentIndex + maxLength < source.Length)
   {
      int prevIndex = currentIndex;
      currentIndex += maxLength;
      while (currentIndex >= 0 && source[currentIndex] != ' ') currentIndex--;
      if (currentIndex <= prevIndex)
             throw new ArgumentException("invalid maxLength");
      yield return source.Substring(prevIndex, currentIndex - prevIndex);
      currentIndex++;
   }
   yield return source.Substring(currentIndex);
}
```

Test case:

```
"this is a test".SplitOnLength(5).ToList()
                .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("|" + x + "|"));
```

Output:

```
|this|
|is a|
|test|
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tested all ways (jay RegEx way, not LINQ one) also I got exception by Dan taos way when I set a maintainWords to true for all position so I skip it.

This is what I'd done:

```
List<DifferentTypes> smallStrings = new List<DifferentTypes>();
List<DifferentTypes> mediomStrings = new List<DifferentTypes>();
List<DifferentTypes> largeStrings = new List<DifferentTypes>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    string strSmallTest = "This is a small string test for different approachs provided here.";

    smallStrings.Add(Approachs(strSmallTest, "small"));

    string mediomSize = "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."
                        + "Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 "
                        + "(Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2003 SP2"
                        + " .NET Framework does not support all versions of every platform. For a list of the supported versions, see .NET Framework System Requirements. ";
    mediomStrings.Add(Approachs(mediomSize, "Mediom"));

    string largeSize =
        "This is a question that I get very frequently, and I always tried to dodged the bullet, but I get it so much that I feel that I have to provide an answer. Obviously, I am (not so) slightly biased toward NHibernate, so while you read it, please keep it in mind." +
        "EF 4.0 has done a lot to handle the issues that were raised with the previous version of EF. Thinks like transparent lazy loading, POCO classes, code only, etc. EF 4.0 is a much nicer than EF 1.0." +
        "The problem is that it is still a very young product, and the changes that were added only touched the surface. I already talked about some of my problems with the POCO model in EF, so I won’t repeat that, or my reservations with the Code Only model. But basically, the major problem that I have with those two is that there seems to be a wall between what experience of the community and what Microsoft is doing. Both of those features shows much of the same issues that we have run into with NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate. Issues that were addressed and resolved, but show up in the EF implementations." +
        "Nevertheless, even ignoring my reservations about those, there are other indications that NHibernate’s maturity makes itself known. I run into that several times while I was writing the guidance for EF Prof, there are things that you simple can’t do with EF, that are a natural part of NHibernate." +
        "I am not going to try to do a point by point list of the differences, but it is interesting to look where we do find major differences between the capabilities of NHibernate and EF 4.0. Most of the time, it is in the ability to fine tune what the framework is actually doing. Usually, this is there to allow you to gain better performance from the system without sacrificing the benefits of using an OR/M in the first place.";

    largeStrings.Add(Approachs(largeSize, "Large"));

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("/////////////////////////");
Console.WriteLine("average small for saeed: {0}", smallStrings.Average(x => x.saeed));
Console.WriteLine("average small for Jay: {0}", smallStrings.Average(x => x.Jay));
Console.WriteLine("average small for Simmon: {0}", smallStrings.Average(x => x.Simmon));

Console.WriteLine("/////////////////////////");
Console.WriteLine("average mediom for saeed: {0}", mediomStrings.Average(x => x.saeed));
Console.WriteLine("average mediom for Jay: {0}", mediomStrings.Average(x => x.Jay));
Console.WriteLine("average mediom for Simmon: {0}", mediomStrings.Average(x => x.Simmon));

Console.WriteLine("/////////////////////////");
Console.WriteLine("average large for saeed: {0}", largeStrings.Average(x => x.saeed));
Console.WriteLine("average large for Jay: {0}", largeStrings.Average(x => x.Jay));
Console.WriteLine("average large for Simmon: {0}", largeStrings.Average(x => x.Simmon));
```

And:

```
private static DifferentTypes Approachs(string stringToDecompose, string text2Write)
{
    DifferentTypes differentTypes;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var strs = stringToDecompose.SaeedsApproach(10);
        foreach (var item in strs)
        { 
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Saeed's Approach takes {0} millisecond for {1} strings", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, text2Write);
    differentTypes.saeed = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var strs = stringToDecompose.JaysApproach(10);
        foreach (var item in strs)
        {
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Jay's Approach takes {0} millisecond for {1} strings", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, text2Write);
    differentTypes.Jay = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        var strs = stringToDecompose.SimmonsApproach(10);
        foreach (var item in strs)
        {
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Simmon's Approach takes {0} millisecond for {1} strings", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, text2Write);
    differentTypes.Simmon = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    return differentTypes;
}
```

The results:

```
average small for saeed: 4.6
average small for Jay: 33.9
average small for Simmon: 5.6

average mediom for saeed: 28.7
average mediom for Jay: 173.9
average mediom for Simmon: 38.7

average large for saeed: 115.3
average large for Jay: 594.2
average large for Simmon: 138.7
```

Test it simply in your PCs and feel free to edit this to leave your test result or improve current function. I'm sure if we test it with larger strings we can see very difference between my approach and yours.

Edit: I edited my approach to use foreach and yield, see my code above. the result is:

```
average small for saeed: 6.5
average small for Jay: 34.5
average small for Simmon: 5.9

average mediom for saeed: 30.6
average mediom for Jay: 157.9
average mediom for Simmon: 35

average large for saeed: 122.4
average large for Jay: 584
average large for Simmon: 157
```

---

Here is my (Jay's) test:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var s =
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, " 
            + "sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore " 
            + "magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, " 
            + "quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl " 
            + "ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem " 
            + "vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit " 
            + "esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat " 
            + "nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto " 
            + "odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue " 
            + "duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor " 
            + "cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id " 
            + "quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent " 
            + "claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit " 
            + "eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod " 
            + "ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, " 
            + "qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam " 
            + "littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit " 
            + "litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima" 
            + ". Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari" 
            + ", fiant sollemnes in futurum.";
        s += s;
        s += s;
        s += s;

        var watch = new Stopwatch();

        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) s.JaysApproach(200).ToList();
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Jay:   {0}", watch.ElapsedTicks / 10000);

        watch.Reset();

        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) s.SaeedsApproach(200);
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Saeed: {0}", watch.ElapsedTicks / 10000);

        watch.Reset();

        watch.Start();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) s.SimonsApproach(200).ToList();
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Simon: {0}", watch.ElapsedTicks / 10000);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
4 lorem ipsums (as shown):
    Jay:   317
    Saeed: 1069
    Simon: 599

3 lorems ipsums:
    Jay:   283
    Saeed: 862
    Simon: 465

2 lorem ipsums:
    Jay:   189
    Saeed: 417
    Simon: 236

1 lorem ipsum:
    Jay:   113
    Saeed: 204
    Simon: 118
```

Comment: My approach returns list and there is no need to execute it by foreach. also i just included the average result.

Comment: Adding the extra `foreach` is unnecessary and is skewing your result. Do something with each result, like `Console.WriteLine()` and you'll get more equitable results.

Comment: @Jay I wrote it with yield and compare them all with extra foreach, we can't use Console.WriteLine because it's very slower than all of approachs (the running time of single writeline is slower than run time one full foreach loop so we can't trust the output result).

Comment: @Jay, and @Simon Mourier, yes for large piece your codes run faster but if you set it to 10, or 20 you will see difference, call by `s.JaysApproach(10)` which is greater than words average size in real life, you will see my performance is better than yours, but yes if K becomes large, because you are not going to split by words your speed will be better. for large strings with small `K` my approach is better and for large string with big K, your approach is better.

Comment: @Jay, Ooooch, if you test my first approach you shouldn't iterate it, because it's an executed experssion, you can test my second approach, which is not executed version and call ToList, your test is not fair, because of this, also check what I said, smallest `K`.

Comment: @Saeed: The reason you got an exception from my answer when you set `maintainWords` to *true* was that there are words in the input string that are too long to fit within the specified `length`. The behavior you get in this scenario needs to be specified and dealt with in any solution to this problem. I opted to go with an exception. However my implementation could easily be changed to behave differently in this case. The important thing is to make your behavior match what the user/client expects. From the OP's question, I don't think that's 100% clear.

Comment: Saeed, what do you mean I shouldn't iterate it? I don't think I am; I call `ToList()` only on mine and Simon's, which are otherwise lazy-evaluated.

Comment: @Jay, if you wanna iterate it, iterate my differed executable sample.