# substring for words

Tags: c#

text:

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem ac

i want to substring words not in regular way like word.Substring(1, 29).

regular way:

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde om"

but i want:

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde"

so only full words are shown. if word is cut inside one word before will be shown. hope understand what i am looking for.

Comment: How do you know what is, and what is not, a word?  Dictionary lookup?

Comment: Possible (?) duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556151/linq-splitting-up-a-string-with-maximum-length-but-not-chopping-words-apart/4556369#4556369

Comment: Sheesh, I guess your C# is better than your English! ;)
But thanks for the question, I had the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static String ParseButDontClip(String original, int maxLength)
{
    String response = original;

    if (original.Length > maxLength)
    {
        int lastSpace = original.LastIndexOf(' ', original.Length - 1, maxLength);
        if (lastSpace > -1)
            response = original.Substring(0, lastSpace);
    }
    return response;
}
```

String.LastIndexOf second's parameter is actually the END of the substring to search for - and longest is how far back towards the start you need to go.

Gets me every time I use it.

Comment: What if his string is this: `Sed ut perspiciatis unde`?  Wouldn't `unde` be stripped out in this case?

Comment: exactly, unde must go out. with last index i always get" Count must be positive and count must refer to a location within the string/array/collection.
Parameter name: count"

Comment: It seems to me like "unde" needs to stay since it is a full word in the original sentence...  Correct?

Comment: dear MS - how about caring for ur devs a bit more and put real summery? voted

Comment: Your solution is great John, however I ran into an issue with it:
With a string length of 25: "DeDouge-Cardyie, Charity A", and max length of 18, the resulting string ends up longer than 18 because the first space it finds occurs after the max length.

My remedy for this was to do:
int lastSpace = original.LastIndexOf(' ', maxLength, maxLength-1);

Still behaves normally, but also catches that one case I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You could split it by white spaces and then play with the array